# How do you plot from a Pandas GroupBy in Bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

I am trying to plot this data using bokeh. I am trying for a line graph but it shows the error in the source and also how do i add the hover tooltip?

Also i got this data after performing group by on a dataframe.

data:

```
books_alloted
Friday       13893
Monday       14471
Saturday     14237
Sunday       11695
Thursday     14731
Tuesday      14900
Wednesday    16073
Name: books_alloted, dtype: int64
```

error:

```
expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got books_alloted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a very old version of Bokeh? As of any recent version you can pass Pandas `GroupBy` objects directly to Bokeh [`ColumnDataSource`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource) objects. When you supply a `GroupBy` the data source will automatically be populated with columns corresponding to the `group.describe` method:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
group = df.groupby('cyl')

source = ColumnDataSource(group)

p = figure(plot_height=350, toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.line(x='cyl', y='mpg_mean', source=source)

show(p)
```

[image]

See the [Pandas Section of *Handling Categorical Data*](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#pandas) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
# read the data
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# generate the plot
p = figure(title="book plot", x_axis_label="dates", y_axis_label="alloted", x_range=df.loc[:,"books"])
p.line(df.loc[:,"books"], df.loc[:,"num"], legend="books", line_width=2) # num is the number of books alloted
show(p)
```

this is the solution:
[image]

Comment: It is not a dataframe, i guess, thats what the error says above

Comment: How do you plot it just right after the grouping it ? that would solve my problem

Comment: Using read_csv only but since I've grouped it using a column name and saved it to a variable. It does not stay as a df i guess

Comment: I did this books_alloted=data.groupby('book_day').count()['c_books']

Comment: How do i plot using the data after groupby, I wanna know that

Comment: can you tell me the output of `type(books_alloted)` or provide the input data? Because `books_alloted` should be a dataframe as well. Or use `books_alloted.reset_index()` and then the solution I provided?